# $27^{2004} + 22^{2004} - 4^{2004} - 1$ is divisible by (options)

Tags: divisibility

(A) $299$     
(B) $296$  
(C) $298$      
(D) $297$

This kind of sums are too problematic. 
Please provide a method which could give the correct answer in about a minute. :)

Comment: No, the answer is $(A)$ but it takes me quite a few minutes to figure that out :-(

Comment: @DiffeoR, sure it can. by your logic $3$ doesn't divide $6$...

Comment: Oh right thanks ! even number will not divide odd, but not vice versa. :D

Comment: Is this really under a minute answer type question ? :P

Comment: Probably yes. No. of questions is almost equal to the no. of minutes proved. (..and the other questions were not so easy :P)

Comment: I think this is doable in a minute only for people trained to factorize small numbers quickly. If one know $299 = 13\times 23$, it is not hard to use this to show the number is divisible by both $13$ and $23$. Of course, if one do this systematically, one will probably try the deal with the factor $2^{?}$ in $296 = 2^3\times 37$ and $298 = 2\times149$ and the factor $3$ in $297 = 3^3\times 11$ first. Those two checks themselves probably cost one a great fraction of a minute and one doesn't have too many seconds left.